# Indesign numbering appendixes in a book

Tags: adobe-indesign, book

I am working on different documents to create a `Book`. I have managed to fix all references, figures, numbering, etc But I do not know how to solve the following problem with appendixes:

I have 3 chapters: Chapter 1, 2 and 3. I have 2 Appendixes: Appendix A and B.
The numbering works fine when I mix them all, but I have a problem with the list of my Figures. It is defined as: `Figure ^H.^#:` so Figures are named `1.1, 1.2... 2.1, 2.2`... etc But when it comes to the appendix they are `4.1, 4.2... 5.1...`  instead of `A.1, A.2... B.1...` because, of course, the appendix is considered one more chapter.

How can I redefine "^H" so it is a letter and not a number in the appendixes? Of course this letter has to increase at every different chapter, such as the number does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering nobody could suggest a better option, the best solution I could find is:

Modify the appendix style to:  `Appendix ^H`  instead of using `Appendix ^1` with the specific list for appendixes.
Then Layout - Numbering and Section Options change to style `"A,B,C..."` in every appendix document, and specify `"start at A"` in the first appendix.

It is not an ideal solution - not automatised, but it does the job.